# Splitting string into single values in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table (table_string) &  data as below, basically trying to split the string values into single value and store in a separate table.

```
ID  Name    ADD  
1   a,b,c   d,e,f  
2   x,y,c   n,e,f  
3   n,b,c   d,e,f  
4   x,y,c   n,e,f
```

After transformation the table data looks like the below .

```
**ID**  Name   ADD  
1       a      d  
1       b      e  
1       c      f  
2       x      n  
2       y      e  
2       c      f and so on....
```

Comment: _'After transformation it looks like'_ and _'I want it to look like'_ do not seem to make sense together. Is that what you get, or is that what you don't get but do want? Also, _"trying to split the string values into single value and store the table"_ is not clear: store where? back into the same table? or a new one? Anyway, you should just search first: this and the converse transformation have been asked and answered hundreds of times (for every imaginable DBMS).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @underscore_d . Need to store it in a different table like the format stated above

Comment: Here I have 2 columns to split. That's why I posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT regexp_substr(Name, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) 
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY regexp_substr(Name, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks @Surface Tension. I am using MYSQL for the above.